# Images not popping up in Outlook when sending newsletter

Tags: image, outlook, newsletter

I send out newsletters for the company I work for. Since graphic artists have to create images, I usually end up testing my newsletters with temporary images that are from older newsletters. But whenever I overwrite the image in my ftp folder with the new one, it will not appear in Dreamweaver. Worst of all, outlook users do not see the image. They will either see the old image or see the red X.

As for me, I use thunderbird and I see the correct the image. The image also correctly appears on the website.

I have tried clearing the cache of dreamweaver, by deleting this file to no avail.:

> Delete C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application
>   Data\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CS6\en_US\Configuration\WinFileCache-xxxxxxxx.dat

This is an example of the code I use

```
<img border="0" src="http://www.******.com/***/***/2013/gpd_banner_fr.jpg" style="display:block;" alt="BANNIÈRE" />
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the URL `http://www.******.com/***/***/2013/gpd_banner_fr.jpg` into the browser, does it exist?

If so, now in Outlook, scroll to the bottom of your email and right click > view source. What URL is showing in your email code?

Assuming it is different, it has something to do with how you are sending it. Are you using an email service provider? How are you uploading the images?

Comment: Yes, it 100% exists. In Outlook, it shows the exact same url. With the correct http:// protocol. I'm uploading my image via an ftp provider, and using a service similar to mail chimp (one based in my city) to send the newsletters.

Comment: When you upload the images, are they zipped first? Could you be uploading the old version? Could your ESP be changing the directory slightly in the URL? This still doesn't make sense though, if you looked at the Outlook source html and it is pointing to an online hosted image, that is what it shows unless there is some sort of caching, which I've never known Outlook to do.

Comment: Not at all, a straight up image with the correct name uploaded into the ftp directly, overwriting the old image. The url does not change at all, as the image can be seen correctly in Thunderbird and in any browser.

Perhaps it is caching? But hell, Microsoft is a real piece of enigmatic crap when it comes to IE and Outlook. So, I wouldn't be surprised? But if Thunderbird doesn't do that, why would Outlook?

Comment: If it is caching, maybe test if it happens on someone else's Outlook, or just yours. Try renaming the email or changing the image url to see if it updates.

Comment: Alright, so I uploaded the same pic with a different name. Still not appearing. So, it can't be cache related, or at least not entirely.

Comment: If you look at your Outlook email source code, does it have the new URL?

Comment: Well no, because the url would be the same, as I overwrote the original pic with a new pic with the same name.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood when you said you uploaded it under a different name. I think I understand what you mean - the original file name you uploaded in your ESP, which doesn't transfer over to the URL. Try changing the image URL completely in the code, so that it points somewhere new. It might refresh it. If the image url absolutely must stay the same, do that to clear it out and then change it back to the original.

Comment: For some reason, I thought you were speaking about the older post. I apologize. The url is the same, except for the number 2 which I added. So, yes the url is different.